# What is the value of $\left\{\frac{3^{1001}}{82}\right\}$

Tags: congruences, fractional-part

Let
$$x=\left\{\frac{3^{1001}}{82}\right\}$$
where $\{\}$ denotes fractional part. What is the value of $x$?

First I noticed that $x=\frac y{82}$ for some $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le y\le81$. But what next? Problem is how to solve $3^{1001}\mod82$. Then I noticed that $82=2\cdot41$, so does it mean that $y$ must be odd because $3^{1001}$ and $82$ doesn't have same parity? Also, is there any conguence pattern for $41$ which can be applied here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:
$$ 3^{1001}\equiv 3^1 \equiv 3\pmod{41} $$
by Fermat's little theorem, while obviously $3^{1001}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.

The Chinese theorem hence gives $3^{1001}\equiv 3\pmod{82}$, so your fractional part is just $\color{red}{\frac{3}{82}}$.

Comment: $3^{1001}\equiv (2)\cdot 3\cdot \left(\frac{1}2 \mod {41} \right)+ (41)\cdot 1\cdot \left(\frac{1}{41}\mod 2 \right)\equiv 6\cdot 21 + 41\cdot 1\equiv 126+41\equiv 167\equiv 3\pmod {82}$.

Comment: @mathh: $3$ is already $\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, so we don't really need to find the inverse of $2\pmod{41}$.

Comment: It is only relevant that $3\cdot \left(\frac{1}2\mod {41}\right)$ exists if you consider $(2)\cdot 3\cdot \left(\frac{1}2 \mod {41} \right)\equiv k\pmod 2$, since the $2$ makes it so that the expression is equivalent to $0\pmod 2$. The inverse of $2\pmod {41}$ is there to make it so that the $2$ disappears when you consider the whole expression $\pmod {41}$ and what is left in the first term of the expression is $3\pmod {41}$, which is the remainder we need ($(41)\cdot 1\cdot \left(\frac{1}{41}\mod 2 \right)\equiv 0\pmod {41}$, so we can ignore the second term $\pmod {41}$).

Comment: We don't care what the inverse of $2\pmod {41}$ is (only that it exists) if we consider the first term $\pmod 2$, since the $2$ in the first already makes it equivalent to $0\pmod 2$, since $0\cdot a\equiv 0\pmod 2, \forall a\in\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$3^4\equiv-1\mod82$ and $1001=250\times4+1$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $3^4 \equiv -1 (\mod 82)$ so that $3^{1001} \equiv 3 (\mod 82)$. That is, $\dfrac{3^{1001}}{82} = k + \dfrac{3}{82}$ for some positive integer $k$.